# Array to return multiple matches in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to find the formula that can return row numbers for the multiple matches in excel column using VBA.  I want to store values for all the rows where match for "267874" was found in columns.  Array should store row number (7:9)

Current formula i am using is 
"countif" to find number of matches
"loop" countif value and store matches in f(i)

```
 - Parent  Child   Row
 - 267873   265501  1
 - 267873   265501  2
 - 267873   265501  3
 - 267873   267879  4
 - 267873   267880  5
 - 267873   267877  6
 - 267874   265472  7
 - 267874   265472  8
 - 267874   265472  9
```

Comment: Post your code, so we can help you.

Comment: I did not post it because it is not working properly.

Comment: That's the point. Post it, say what's wrong and then we will try suggest modifications to it.

Comment: @ShriCode thats ok. Just tell us where its going sour and we can help with that.

Comment: Did you consider using filters? Filter data, go through visible cells and put its' rows into an array.

Comment: Since in a hierarchy table you will likely only search 2 columns, you could use a recordset instead of an array. Posted an example here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858733/vba-match-function-nested-for-loops-troubleshooting/45860225#45860225] and use a `.Filter = "[Parent] = 267874 OR [Child] = 267874"`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim lRow As Long, iCell As Range, arrRow(), i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("YourSheetNameHere")
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arrRow(lRow)
    ws.Range("A5", "E" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*Invalid*"
    i = 0
    For Each iCell In ws.Range("A6", "A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        arrRow(i) = iCell.Row
        i = i + 1
    Next
    ReDim Preserve arrRow(i - 1)
End Sub
```

*Before:*
[image: Before]
*After:*
[image: After]
*Result:*
[image: Result]